# What is going on with this Rails model? Why doesn't it save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I believe this should be saving in the database, but it is not, and it is not giving an error either. This is the User model.

```
irb(main):232:0* u.email = "cat@mandu.com"
=> "cat@mandu.com"
irb(main):233:0> u.email.encrypt!
=> "a/5MHjJ5n9HTqYATiBOAc9IdowaAWMyUpDRD4dT1b80="
irb(main):234:0> u.email
=> "a/5MHjJ5n9HTqYATiBOAc9IdowaAWMyUpDRD4dT1b80="
irb(main):235:0> u.save
=> true
irb(main):236:0> u.email
=> "a/5MHjJ5n9HTqYATiBOAc9IdowaAWMyUpDRD4dT1b80="
irb(main):237:0> u.reload
=> #<User id: 1, username: "starrychloe", password: "400$8$5a$1cb7a05469a179ca$e86839f656b5b0541fe2a2f63...", last_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2013-09-30 02:29:28", updated_at: "2014-01-14 06:16:59", email: "cat@mandu.com", nameOnCard: "", creditCard: "", expirationMonth: "", expirationYear: "", address1: "", address2: "", city: "", state: "", zip: "">
irb(main):238:0> u.email
=> "cat@mandu.com"
irb(main):239:0>
```

This is the only validation in the model:

```
validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i }, unless: "email.blank?", on: :create, length: {maximum: 255}
```

Here is the ecrypt! method:

```
module Encryptor
  def encrypt!
    replace encrypt
  end

end
String.send(:include, Encryptor)
```

Comment: Did you try to save the record without encryption?

Comment: @majioa Yes saving without encryption works.

Comment: So, either remove format validation, or validate with `proc` to plain email format, or to encrypted one.

Comment: @majioa Check the end of the line. `on: :create, `. Validation should not matter. This is an existing model.

Comment: Try changing u.email.encrypt! to u.email = u.email.encrypt

Comment: aha, so you have `u.persisted? == true` before save, correct?

Comment: Also, you can replace `unless: "email.blank?"` to `allow_blank: true`.

Comment: For example, also (after validation that `u.persisted?` is `false`)  try: `validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/, allow_blank: true, length: 0..255, on: :create`

Comment: @teeg No I am not using --sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `u.email.encypt!` bypasses the setter for email attribute, this may be the cause of the problem. I guess changing  `u.email.encrypt! to u.email = u.email.encrypt!`  will work.

Comment: I added the `encrypt!` method. Is that relevant?

Comment: That was it! Some reason it did not recognize any changes!

Comment: This is because you replace content of u.email without using u.email = . Underlying Rails stores new value of u.email somewhere when you use u.email =, and when the user get saved, rails get the new value from there. By using String#encrypt! you change value of u.email but does not change it underlying value, so you see the old value of u.email when the user get saved.